# In WinRT XAML - tapping and clicking on a button is not the same?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

When hooking the Tapped event on a page (so I can get all events that are not caught by children), I am also getting the event fired when a user taps a button on the page.

I would have expected the button to "swallow" the tap, but that does not seem to be the case.

The workaround is simple, if annoying - hook the Tap event on each button present and set Handled to true. I get how to do the workaround.

My question is whether or not I am understanding this correctly. If hooking the Tap event on all my buttons that are on the page (so I don't get the tap event on the page fired) really the correct way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle the `Click` event on the button, not the `Tapped` event. If the `Tapped` event still bubbles to the page - yes, by all means, handle it on the button and mark it `Handled` to prevent bubbling or try to change the `IsTapEnabled` value on the button.
If handling the event is the only way and you don't like the code behind - you can either have all button `Tapped` events use the same handler or define an attached behavior that does the swallowing in a separate class where you define the behavior.

Comment: That seems like a pretty weird design to me. But ah well.

Comment: @Filip Skakun I used e.handled = true; and solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: Glad this still helps someone!