# How to put button inside grid that can be tapped in Windows 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm developing an app for windows 8.1. I have a grid that can be tapped, and now I want to put button inside this grid to provide some finer function. What should I do so that when I click the button, the event inside the grid will not be triggered. The code structure is like this

```
<Grid Tapped = "OnGridTapped" Background = "Transparent">
    <Button Tapped = "OnButtonTapped"/>
</Grid>
```

I cannot have to access to `BringToFront()` or `Zindex` thus it is a problem.

Comment: i think this should solve your Problem: [In WinRT XAML - tapping and clicking on a button is not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542972/in-winrt-xaml-tapping-and-clicking-on-a-button-is-not-the-same)

Comment: @PatrickGuttmann  I used e.handled = true; which is mentioned in this post and solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Circular Image Xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138878/create-circular-image-xaml)

Comment: @ChrisW. Totally different thing...this one is about event handling that link is about layout

Comment: Ah, well a lot of times it's as easy as adding [ClickMode=Press](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.clickmode) to the button base to segregate the hit area from it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `OnButtonTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)` just add `e.handled = true` will stop tap event bubble up to Grid thus solve the problem